# Condition for poles to be eigenvalues

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $F_{fg}(z)=(f,R_H(z)g)$  where $R_H(z)\equiv(H-z)^{-1}$ is the resolvent and $f,g$ are vectors for a dense set $A$ in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Suppose that $F_{fg}(z)$ has meromorphic continuation in $\Omega$ 
 given $F_{fg}(z,\theta)\equiv (U(\theta)f,R_{H(\theta)} U(\theta)g).$
where $R_{H(\theta)}\equiv(H(\theta)-z)^{-1}$ with  $H(\theta)\equiv U(\theta)HU(\theta)^*.$ Here $U(\theta)$ is an operator such that for $\theta \in R $ is unitary and $U(\theta)^*$ is the adjoint.

What are the conditions  satisfied by $U(\theta)A$, such that for $\theta \in  D \equiv \{\theta \in \mathcal{C}:\sigma_{ess}(H(\theta))\cap \Omega=\varnothing\},$ the poles of the continuation of $F_{fg}(z)$ into $\Omega$, are eigenvalues of  the operators $H(\theta)$ 
?

Here $\sigma_{ess}$ is the essential spectrum.

Textbook says that $U(\theta)A$ should be dense in $A$ and to use the argument principle to show that , if $h\notin A$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $x$ than there is a sequence of function $F_n=(f_n,R_{H(\theta)} g_n)$,such that  for some $n_0 \in \mathcal{N}$ the  function $F_{n_0}=(f_{n_0},R_{H(\theta)} g_{n_0})$ has a pole at $x$.

But all i can do is to proof that the function $F_{n_0}$ has a pole in a neighborhood of $x_0$ by the argument principle. 
Can anyone one proof that $F_{n_0}$ has a pole  at $x_0$?